# Autofac System.OutOfMemoryException: Array dimensions exceeded supported range

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

We have ASPNET MVC WEB API and we use Autofac (Version=4.9.4) as DI. We are getting a lot of exceptions thrown by Autofac now with high number of API requests.

```
An error occurred while processing request: System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'PortalControllerV1'. 
Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor. ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating 
PortalControllerV1 -> 
    Entities.PasswordPolicyHelper. ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(IoC.Services.IAppSettingsProvider, IApplicationLazyCache)' on type 'PasswordPolicyHelper'. ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating ?:Configuration.RemoteSyncConfigurationRoot. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Array dimensions exceeded supported range.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1.Push(T item)
   at Autofac.Core.Disposer.AddInstanceForDisposal(IDisposable instance) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Disposer.cs:line 78
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& decoratorTarget) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 145
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 83
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 131
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 1041
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 871
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 300
```

It seems that we exceeded the supported range of the stack of Autofac Disposer. Any idea how to solve this? Is it a bug in Autofac?

Comment: Autofac is on 7.0.1 now. 4.9.4 is 4 years old. Try updating.

Comment: Yes, we have a plan to update it but it is not at the moment. Also we need to know if updating would actually solve this issue. I see that Disposer class is still using Stack field

Comment: But you'll also see the Stack has no limit set, so it'd be whatever the limit of .NET is. I say upgrade because the internals have changed a lot since then and you may get fewer things stuck in that stack.